# jQuery's tabletogrid example

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a HTML table and I would like to change the table to grid using jQuery's JQGrid plugin.

How would i do that?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){      
tableToGrid("#distTable"); 
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<table id="distTable">
<thead>
<tr> 
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Size</th>       
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">102803</td>
                        <td align="center">102803d22222222222222222222222222222222222222gs</td>
                        <td align="center">21587231</td>
                    </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">102803</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">10280311111111111111111111111</td>
                <td align="center">102803dgs</td>
                <td align="center">215872321</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Where and how I would be adding the jQuery script?

Comment: have you went through the documentation of plugin.....in that you will find where and how to add jQuery script?

Comment: @Vivek: need little help from you. I tried with one example: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
tableToGrid("#distTable"); 
}); but yet i am not getting the grid layout.

Comment: have you included that jQgrid plugin..just checkin...if yes..then try this one...jQuery(document).ready(function(){("#distTable").tableToGrid();});.....may be this helps you....but still i am not aware of this plugin...but this is the way to call a function in jQuery...Let me know this works for you or not?

Comment: @Vivek, Yes i have included all the files. Will try your suggestion and update you soon.

Comment: and i think you have not given id to your table in your HTML....first do that..and your id should be distTable,....according to your code

Comment: @Vivek: I tried, But does not work. I have updated my code. Just review it!

Comment: DO it as i have written it in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this.....
in HTML..........

```
<table id="distTable" border="2px" padding="7px 7px 7px 7px" border-style=" solid" >
```

and in your code should be...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

         ("#distTable").tableToGrid();

      });
```

Comment: @Vivek: I changed/modified everything. but it is not working. If you are getting the results mail me as attachments to ashwinkumark10@gmail.com

Comment: this explanation might be help you http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid...

Comment: @vivek: Thanks a lot! I downloaded the pdf documentation and read everything completely. I then understood how to make it work.