# Add JQGrid on an Existing Table in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid, html-table

I have a table in my JSP page. It contains more than 100 rows.

```
<table id="grid">
    <tr>
    <th>Inv No</th>
    <th> Thingy</th>
    <th> Blank</th>
    <th> Number</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    <td>fgdfg</td>
    </tr>

<!-- More than 100 rows -->

</table>
```

I want to add JQuery grid to this table with 20 rows on each page. [Here is the link what I have tried](http://jsfiddle.net/shijukbabu/KMjNM/). But nothing works.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Refer the link [Table to Jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426472/jquerys-tabletogrid-example)..

Comment: Also You could refer jqgrid official link [jqgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under that New in version 3.3 - Html table to grid.